# MATLAB submitWithConfiguration

Tags: matlab, submit

I am having trouble using the submit() command in MATLAB. The error I get trying to submit a file is

```
       Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: .\lib 
     > In path (line 109)
       In addpath (line 88)
       In submit (line 2) 
       Undefined function or variable 'submitWithConfiguration'.
```

I am not adding the actual file content because I don't think it is relevant in this case, but if I am wrong please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

My code is:

```
    function A = warmUpExercise()
%WARMUPEXERCISE Example function in octave
%   A = WARMUPEXERCISE() is an example function that returns the 5x5 identity matrix

% ============= YOUR CODE HERE ==============
% Instructions: Return the 5x5 identity matrix 
%               In octave, we return values by defining which variables
%               represent the return values (at the top of the file)
%               and then set them accordingly. 

A = eye(5);
```

Comment: This btw is *Warning*; not error. Making your problem reproducible *is always relevant*. See [MCVE]

Comment: The error is that it didn't submit. The point is, my changing the content of the file  does not change the warning message and failure to submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Matlab cannot find `submitWithConfiguration.m` (likely under directory `lib`). Fix it by adding the folder containing `submitWithConfiguration.m` to the search path.

If you are submitting a file to Coursera for example. You need to unzip the provided code to your working directory where you will find the `lib` directory inside. Please check that.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your MATLAB isn't accessing the *'submitWithConfiguration.mat'* file.
One way to solve this issue is, if you go in '*submit()*' function and manually add path from your 'lib' folder then it may work, also add the path of '*jsonsave*' file. Second solution is that you can copy all the child folder data into parent folder (which contains your '*submit().mat*' function), hopefully it should work

Answer (score 1):

If you have still faced with this problem, specifically for Online version of Matlab, you might find a solution like this:

1. Download the zip file from coursera website which contains all the exercise files.
2. upload the all file plus subfolder of lib inside the online Matlab directory you are working with. If you do do not upload lib subfolder, you cannot submit your files.
3. After completing your exercise, then execute submit function which helps you submit your work.
4. Enter your email and token code and receive submit confirmation.

Comment: for me lib folder file was missing. Thanks it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the online version, on the left side there should be a directory explorer. Right click on the folder that contains the script file, and press "add to path" - then choose "Selected Folders and Subfolders" - this will insure that source files that are in subfolders will also be recognized by the command prompt / main script.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, the lib folder was under exercise 1 folder but it was greyed out.

I right-clicked on it and selected ***add to the path*** and then chose **include folder and subfolder**:

[image]

After that submit started to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MATLAB Online, just open the `lib` folder and copy the path of the folder. Further, just paste the path in function `submit` like this:

```
function submit()
addpath('./MATLAB Drive/machine-learning-ex/ex1/lib');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution on youtube. There was something missing in another solution of changing variable and other stuff and it is shown perfectly in this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POpgzrlU47I